# How to highlight rows if not matching comparing each line individually

Tags: excel

I have a file in an excel sheet that has two columns. I want to compare line by line of both columns and highlight if any rows aree different.

In the picture below, row 12,14,15 should be highlighted (both cells in column A and column B).

[image]

Is there a way to do this in excel?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 0):

Use below conditional formatting rule-

```
=$A2<>$B2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What if the columns are not beside each other? For example, the values are found in column A and C, but not B, and I dont't want B to be highlighted?

Comment: Then use =$A2<>$C2